# Farm Setup account unable to access site collection

Tags: 2013, site-collection, farm-setup

I used account SP_Setup to install SharePoint. This account is not only the site collection administrator but also added in "Owners" group in that site collection but when I try to open site collection I get error message

> Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you

This user is also added in Farm Administrator group in Central Administration.

If I open site collection using Farm Account which is SP_Farm then it is working fine.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Did you add the SP_Setup user by name to the Owners group in the root site or did you add them by group (eg. Domain Admins?) If you haven't set up User Profile sync, groups may be unavailable to SharePoint for permissions use.

Answer (score 0):

The setup account doesn't necessarily have access to a site collection. Adding it to Farm Administrator group has no effect either.

Does the "Owners" SPGroup have effective permissions on the site (normally it would, but you or someone could have removed permissions for that group altogether) ?

What happens if you do a permission check of that account for the site? Does it return a permission set?